# Slow MongoDB insertion

Tags: mongodb, azure, php-5.6, azure-load-balancer

I have 2 servers one AWS and one Microsoft azure VM and both are 8 core 32 GB.

I am using below script on both servers to check the speed of insert in MongoDB.
On AWS instance I get average 3 seconds with localhost and LAN IP.
On Microsoft azure I get 3 seconds with localhost but on LAN IP its 30 seconds.
I checked the network speed (approx 1.73 Gbits/sec) and its almost same on both servers.

1. Both have standard SSD.
2. MongoDB versions are same.
3. Both have wiredTiger storage engine.

Only difference is Azure application is on load balancer and AWS application is not.

```
if($_REQUEST['mongo']=='localserver'){
    $mongoip        =   "localhost";
}elseif($_REQUEST['mongo']=='mongoserver'){
    $mongoip        =   "x.x.x.x";/* LAN IP of dedicated mongo server */
}
$a              =   "mongo_speed_check";
$mongo_dbname   =   "speed";
try {
    $maa        =   new MongoClient("mongodb://{$mongoip}/{$mongo_dbname}");
    $dbnew1     =   $maa->selectDB($mongo_dbname);
} catch ( MongoConnectionException $e ) {
    print_r($e);
}
$time_start     =   microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++){
    $dbnew1->$a->insert(array('i' =>$i,"field{$i}" => $i * 2));
}
$time_end           =   microtime(true);
$execution_time     =   ($time_end - $time_start);
echo '<br><b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' seconds';
```

Can someone please advise me what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Time the first insert separately from the other inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Time the first insert separately from the other inserts.

The client performs topology discovery and needs to establish connections before it can issue any requests. This happens in background but effectively makes the first operation longer.

If you are testing for throughput, you need to perform at least one operation of the type you are testing to get this initial work done so that it does not skew your results. So, perform one insert (untimed), then time the next 100000 inserts on the same client.

If you are testing initial connection time, time a single insert.

If you *want* high performance, you should be using bulk writes instead of inserting each document individually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how does it work fine on AWS?

Comment: What is it and what is fine?

Comment: On AWS server time is less than 3 seconds for 10000 inserts.

Comment: That seems normal.